# Rollback a transaction in Spring if an exception occurs in a method after the database transaction

Tags: spring

```
Class A{
@Autowired
private B b;

 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
 public void run(){
   try{
    b.insert1();
    b.insert2();
    b.sendFile();

}catch(Exception e){
  //Exception block
}

 }
}

Class B{
  public void insert1(){//db insert happens here}
  public void insert2(){//db insert happens here}

  public void sendFile() throws Exception{

  }

}
```

In the above case rollback works perfectly if insert2 method fails.
But if insert1 and insert2 are completed and sendFile has an exception, rollback is not happening.

Please help me for this. I am stuck with this for the last 2 days.

Thanks

Comment: What if you remove try-catch part?

Comment: Thanks. No. I am handling some other features in the Exception part. So it is not possible to remove that

Comment: Have you found the solution?